# Matlab coder and command-line workflow

Tags: matlab

I would like to use the Matlab coder to create a C/C++ dynamic library. I have a bunch of m-files (functions), which all take a scalar struct with the same fields and some other simple parameters (scalar double etc.). As there are many m- files, I would like to use the ‘command-line workflow’ to use the ‘scalar struct argument definition’ for each m- file/function (basically use ‘programmatic’ code generation instructions).

Is anyone aware of a ‘matlab coder command-line workflow’ example with more than one  m-file, which uses at least one struct definition?

I also tried to ‘export project setting’, in the believe that this will generate some text file that contains the ‘programmatic’ code generation instructions. Unfortunately, I cannot find this file after the export. It is not in the project related folder. Any ideas where it would be? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Are you unable to get the matlab coder to work at all? (You're using [this](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) software, yes?) Are you just looking for a way to loop across your m-files and compile each one in turn to c-code?

Comment: I may delete this question actually. Made some progress in the meantime. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606645/codegen-and-scalar-struct-argument Hope this answers your question ...

Answer (score 0):

I may delete this question actually. Made some progress in the meantime. See here:

[SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13606645/codegen-and-scalar-struct-argument)

I leave this 'answer' for now, in case someone stumbles upon this.