# codegen and scalar struct argument

Tags: matlab

Codegen commands like this:

```
codegen -config:dll ep1 -args single(0) ep2 -args {0,0}
```

are easy for functions like this:

```
function y = ep1(u) %#codegen
y = u;

function y = ep2(u, v) %#codegen
y = u + v;
```

I am just wondering how to define scalar struct arguments. Let us assume that the above argument u should look like this (i.e. consist of 2 fields - one char and one double):

```
u.FirstName = 'Loren';
u.Height = 150
```

PS:

Just found something like this:

```
s = struct('a',42,'b',4711);
codegen topfun.m -args { s }
```

would this be a solution? I believe, this is a definition by example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
codegen -report -config:dll ep1 ...
                            ep2
```

The actual 'function signature' (and thus scalar struct) can be defined in the function like this:

```
function [bla] = ep1(parameters)
%#codegen

assert(isstruct(parameters));
assert(isa(parameters.x1,'char'));
assert(size(parameters.x1, 1) >= 1);
assert(size(parameters.x1, 1) <= 1024);
assert(isa(parameters.x2,'double'));
...
```

Problem I have is that I seem to have to define all the parameters in the parent functions even-though I do not use the parameter in the parent function.

Looking at the stuff above. Let us say ep1 is the parent function of ep2 and ep1 does not use parameters.x2, I still have to assert it in ep1.Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The definitions of the structs can be captured using the `coder.typeof` function.

First initialise the structs using a script, capture the struct definitions using coder.typeof and then pass the definitions using -args as shown below:

```
u = Initialise(u);
p = InitialiseParameters();

tx = coder.typeof(u);
tp = coder.typeof(p);

codegen topfun.m -args {tx, tp} -config:dll
```